# Popup distorts and pushes the page width, how do I fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've recently started learning about css and I've having a problem with the width being altered when the popup is created. Its alters the page so much the header is pushed to the left.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application','//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

    <div class="container">
        <% if notice %> 

            <div id="flash_wrapper">
  <p class="alert alert-notice"><%= notice %></p>
      </div>
      <% elsif alert %> 
          <div id="flash_wrapper">
  <p class="alert alert-info"><%= alert %></p>
      </div>
      <% end %> 

        <%= yield %>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Css of the page

```
 body {
  margin: 0;
    background: url(37.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    top: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.modal.fade.in .modal-dialog {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -300px, 0);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The Animation Popup

```
<p class='text-center'>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo">
  Open Modal
</button>
</p>

<div class="modal fade" id="demo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h1 class="modal-title">Demo Modal</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Pretty Nifty eh?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the code but please could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? With the code you have provided so far it appears likely that this is because you haven't positioned the `div` absolutely.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Those are twitter bootstrap class names, but I don't see where bootstrap is being loaded in your code. I use bootstrap modals myself and they work fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see in your CSS if modal-dialog has

```
position:absolute
```

This is likely what you need for the popup to sit on top of other content.